# How to improve nodejs lambda performance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have deployed my nodejs api on lambda.Everything is working fine but I am getting a very high response time(around 2 seconds).Is there anyway I could reduce this response time?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If this is indeed about AWS, you should have seen that the `lambda` tag *explicitly* says "DO NOT USE FOR THE AWS SERVICE". Please make sure any tag you use is indeed correct for the question.

Comment: Let's try just return a text `Hello World`, and check response time again. If it still keeps in high value, report issue to AWS.

Comment: Or maybe you can post the code?

Comment: Is the 2 second response time on a cold start or on a warm start? What exactly is your code doing (perhaps you should include the code in your question)? Is it running inside a VPC? Have you tried increasing the amount of memory allocated to the function (this also increases the CPU resources available to a Lambda function).

Comment: Also how are you invoking your function? Directly or via another method like API gateway? What is the reported invocation time in the CloudWatch logs?

Answer (score 0):

Either in your Cloudformation templates or in the AWS Console itself under basic settings it is possible to increase Memory and therefore CPU.
This can speedup your lambda.